# Golang decode base64 data to string

Tags: string, go, base64, slice

I am trying to decode a simple base64 encoded string in golang.

```
package main
import b64 "encoding/base64"
import fmt

func main() {
    data := "YmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgc3RyaW5n"
    sDec, err1 := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
    fmt.Println(sDec)
    fmt.Println(err1)
}
```

And the output I get is

```
[98 97 115 101 54 52 32 101 110 99 111 100 101 100 32 115 116 114 105 110 103] // this is the decoded data.
<nil>
```

Where as https://www.base64decode.net/ decodes and outputs as

```
base64 encoded string
```

How do I get the same result in golang?

Comment: looks like that handy site has a golang demo https://www.base64decode.net/golang-decodestring

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)` (which is [`base64.Encoding.DecodeString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.DecodeString)) returns you the decoded data as byte slice (`[]byte`), and this is what you see printed: the decimal representation of the individal bytes.

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the byte slice to `string` if you want to see it as a `string` value:

```
fmt.Println(string(sDec))
```

Or use a format string where you specify you want to print is as a `string`:

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", sDec)
```

Then the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZfbBnUMi8y)):

```
base64 encoded string
```